# tex4ht configuration

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to convert some TeX files to html, for this I am using tex4ht. I am also using myconfig.cfg to produce html file. 
In this config file I have declared following two lines to translate `\textit` and `\textbf` declarations to `<span class"italic>data</span>`
and `<span class"bold>data</span>`.

```
\Configure{textit}{\HCode{`<span class="italic">`}}{\HCode{`</span>`}}<br />
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{`<span class="bold">`}}{\HCode{`</span>`}}
```

After running through tex4ht using the command htlatex test5 "myconfig, fn-out", output is

```
<span class="italic"><span class="t1xi-x-x-109">italic</span></span> 
<span class="bold"><span class="t1xb-x-x-109">bold</span></span>
```

my question is how to tell tex4ht to not to generate `<span class="t1xi-x-x-109"> and <span class="t1xb-x-x-109">`.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can disable generating of such classes with `\NoFonts ... \EndNoFonts` command:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<span class="italic">}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<span class="bold">}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span>}}
\Css{.bold{font-weight:bold;}}
\Css{.italic{font-style:italic;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

```xml
<p class="noindent" >
<span class="bold">hello</span> <span class="italic">world</span> 
</p>
```

Comment: @michal.h21 Somewhere I found `\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</em>}}`. What is `\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi` purpose?

Comment: @mmj It requests closing of previous paragraph in the case it wasn't closed yet. When that happens invalid `xml` code may be produced.